# Ejabberd/Erlang get custom XML Element from Packet

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Ejabberd newbie here...
I am trying to use Ejabberd API to send in custom XML for message statuses from an external service. This external service uses the Ejabberd 'send_stanza' back to the Ejabberd to alert the xmpp user the status of the message. When I send in a received message type or error message type, all is good.

What I am trying to do now is to add a custom tag so that the module (based on filter_packet) can make decisions based on the "app" sending in the packet.

So assume I have this API call:

```
{
  "from": "user1@myxmppserver.com",
  "to": "user2@myxmppserver.com/gajim.LWMH0CHS",
  "stanza": "<message type='error' from='user1@myxmppserver.com' id='f8972327-85e3-4095-a9e3-4761b66bf503' to='user2@myxmppserver.com/gajim.LWMH0CHS'><origin-id xmlns='urn:xmpp:sid:0' id='f8972327-85e3-4095-a9e3-4761b66bf503'/><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/><markable xmlns='urn:xmpp:chat-markers:0'/><appsource appid='external_app'/></message>"
}
```

So notice this part of the message:

```
 <appsource appid='external_app'/>
```

Here is a snippet of the module:

```
check_packet(Packet) ->
?INFO_MSG("check_packet Packet ~p",[Packet]),

El = xmpp:encode(Packet),
Source = fxml:get_path_s(El, [{elem, "appsource"}, {attr, "appid"}]),
?INFO_MSG("check_packet Source=~p",[Source]).
```

The Source variable always returns: <<>>

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like i figured it out - for others this worked for me:
El = xmpp:encode(Packet),
Source = fxml:get_subtag(El, <<"appsource">>),

Answer (score 0):

Right, instead of strings, use binaries:

```
Source = fxml:get_path_s(El, [{elem, <<"appsource">>}, {attr, <<"appid">>}]),
```